# Loop going through directions

Tags: java, loops

I'm learning to work with images, and now i want to calculate the radius of a circle in an image knowing the distance from the center of the circle to a point of it's edge. The thing is that because of the pixels, the radius will change it's value depending on the direction i choose to measure the distance. So the idea is to measure the distance in various directions(starting at angle of 0 degrees and increased in 20 degrees until reach 360) and make an average radius. Using for loop, how can i make it go through that 
changing direction?

[The image with the circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1ydG.png)

Comment: Hi. I am reviewing your post. Your question is good, but to help the community help you, it is always a good idea to add some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an alternative, possibly crazy, suggestion.

If you know the coordinates of a pixel in the circle, use this as the seed point for a flood-fill to identify the number of white pixels in the connected region, i.e. the circle. This gives you the area of the circle, in pixels, and from this you can estimate the radius, via `r = sqrt(area/pi)`

It's probably best if you first threshold the image to produce a grayscale version. Then you can get the area of a region from a seed point using something like this:

```
static int regionSize(BufferedImage im, int sx, int sy)
{
    if (im.getType() != BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    byte[] pix = ((DataBufferByte) im.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
    int w = im.getWidth();
    int h = im.getHeight();

    Queue<Integer> q = new LinkedList<>();

    int seedPos = sy * w + sx;
    q.offer(seedPos);

    boolean[] seen = new boolean[pix.length];

    int area = 0;
    while (!q.isEmpty())
    {
        int j = q.poll();
        int x = j % w;
        int y = j / w;
        area++;

        if (x > 0 && !seen[j - 1] && pix[j - 1] == pix[seedPos])
        {
            seen[j - 1] = true;
            q.offer(j - 1);
        }
        if (x < w - 1 && !seen[j + 1] && pix[j + 1] == pix[seedPos])
        {
            seen[j + 1] = true;
            q.offer(j + 1);
        }
        if (y > 0 && !seen[j - w] && pix[j - w] == pix[seedPos])
        {
            seen[j - w] = true;
            q.offer(j - w);
        }
        if (x < h - 1 && !seen[j + w] && pix[j + w] == pix[seedPos])
        {
            seen[j + w] = true;
            q.offer(j + w);
        }
    }
    return area;
}
```

Test:

```
BufferedImage im = ImageIO.read(new File("images/c1ydGg.png"));

int area = regionSize(im, im.getWidth()/2, im.getHeight()/2);       
System.out.format("Area: %d%n", area);      
double radius = Math.sqrt(area/Math.PI);        
System.out.format("Radius: %f%n", radius);
```

Output:

```
Area: 49607
Radius: 125.659852
```

Which seems pretty close, based on some measurements made in GIMP.

Comment: Its kind of crazy yeah but that's fine, it makes it more fun.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding this question correct. But If you know the centre of the circle.

You can do the below steps:

- 1. get centre value in pixel (ex. 30, 40) and set variable radius = 0;
- 2. move either in x-axis or y-axis by 1 pixel. (ex. 30,41)
- 3. get RGB at the above step pixel (ex. 30,41); if its 255, then increment radius + 1.

Repeat step 2 and 3, till RGB value is 0 for the pixel in black/white image.

Comment: Yes thats the idea but the radius value change with the direction choosed, so its all about move in directions between axes with a certain angle to measure radius and make an average.